# how to access 404 error using retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm accessing a REST API using retrofit 2 To insert JSON data with the raw body and I'm getting success response from server but while I m getting 404 error with response

> **I want to access 404 error please help me to solve this issue**

```
ApiUtil.getServiceClass().sendFinalCart(new ConfirmCartData(_id, sharedPrefManager.getUserID(), grandtotal,
    grandquantity, DDK, payableprice, redeemQuantityModels)).enqueue(new Callback < CardAddToCart > () {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call < CardAddToCart > call, Response < CardAddToCart > response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            cardAddToCart = response.body();

            float result = cardAddToCart.getCartSuccess().getBalance();
            float payablePrice = cardAddToCart.getCartSuccess().getPayablePrice();
            float required = cardAddToCart.getCartSuccess().getRequired();


        } else {
            if (response.code() == 404) {
                cardAddToCart = response.body();

                try {
                    success = response.errorBody().string();
                    Toast.makeText(RedeemCartScreen.this, "" + success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            success = cardAddToCart.getSuccess();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call < CardAddToCart > call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

> And my response for 404 error is like this.

```
{
"success": "not enough balance, pleace recharge ddk wallet",
"result": {
    "balance": 1,
    "payablePrice": 85,
    "amountSaved": null,
    "required": -14.555
}
```

}

> Success response (200).

```
{
  "success": "transection successfull",
  "result": {
    "balance": 1,
    "payablePrice": 100,
    "amountSaved": 0,
    "required": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the codes in your json from your back-end team and then your can compare the result with code and can do your stuff with help of code send by your  back-end team
:-

in your not enough balance state:-

```
{
"success": "not enough balance, pleace recharge ddk wallet",
"code": 200,
"isBalance": false,  //it means you dont have enough balance
"result": {
    "balance": 1,
    "payablePrice": 85,
    "amountSaved": null,
    "required": -14.555
}
```

and in your success case:-

```
{
  "success": "transection successfull",
  "code": 200,
  "isBalance": true, // it means you have sufficient balance
  "result": {
    "balance": 1,
    "payablePrice": 100,
    "amountSaved": 0,
    "required": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: But the response for error is coming in 404 status and Success in 200.So the response should come in 200 Status like this.

Comment: yes if the api response suucess then the code will be 200 and when data not found or other issue then the code will not 200 and in your case you can set another check in your api for insufficient balance but you can not compare with 404

Comment: in your both condition the code should be 200 or in case insufficient balance you should maintain any other check

Comment: Bro can you say in detail  so i can explain to my back-end team to give success and error in 200 HTTP request code so i can access in response.isSuccessful() and is check with code.

Comment: you can set a boolean variable in your json and flow your code according to your boolean value in am updating my answer

Comment: Thanks for the ans bro but same API is called for web application so back-end team is giving error response in 404  so problem created let me share with my team thanks.

Comment: i don't know who give you advice to play with 404 code

Comment: No one the back-end team played with 404 :(

Comment: then how they are doing that you can't do ?

Comment: I am also stuck with backend team. They do not know when to send 404..