# Retrofit 400 response shows required json but does not fall in retrofit isSuccessful block?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

When I hit Login Api

```
data class LoginRequest(val Email: String, val Password: String )

@POST("api/signin")
suspend fun login(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequest): Response<LoginResponse>
```

I get following logs

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 https://phonegateway.xyzdomain.com:5002/api/signin (1760ms)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: correlationid: 0bf23c3a-35a4-4f1b-9c2c-914e6303a7fb
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-powered-by: ASP.NET
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Mon, 14 Jun 2021 12:09:59 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"status":null,"data":null,"message":"User does not exist","code":"400"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (72-byte body)
```

Above logs contain required result  that is all I need

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"status":null,"data":null,"message":"User does not exist","code":"400"}
```

but retrofit  response is not successful

```
if(response.isSuccessful) {
 // I expect this block to be run...
} else { 
     Log.e("source- ",  response.errorBody()?.source().toString())
     // Now I have to extract the result from response.errorBody()?.source().toString()
 }
```

Because response is not successful so I have to extract result from errorbody.source

```
E/source-: [size=72 text={"status":null,"data":null,"message":"User does not exist","code…]
```

And on Postman, I am receiving 400 too. Attached is the image

[image]

which is of course not a correct way. What I am doing wrong in handling response??

Comment: Have you checked the API in Postman or somewhere? It seems that the API is responding 400 due to failure.

Comment: Yes, Postman is returing 400 too But is it not possible to extract the required json response if code is 400. As it is handled by IOS guy easily.

Comment: what do you mean is not the correct way? You described the correct behaviour - you get an HTTP code that is no `2xx`, retrofit marks the response as unsuccessful and populates the error body. You then have to manually extract it. There are quite some good reasons for this behaviour. Is it somehow unexpected for you?

Comment: OK. any standard way to extract data from error body?  What I require is inside errorbody().source and that requires looping and extracting. I want it to be mapped as Pojo class as when response is successful.

Comment: Question is also relevant to this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180214/how-to-access-404-error-using-retrofit-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If the API call is wrapped into a `Response` then okhttp won't throw an exception, rather it will return with a response which has the attribute isSuccessful == false.

What you can do, is to add an error interceptor and throw an IoException if the response was not successful.